# How to fix "not enough values to unpack" when trying to plot 3D data as colormesh?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, random, colors

With `matplotlib` I am trying to plot 3D data as a 2D colormap. Each point has a `x` and a `y` coordinate, and a 'height' `z`. This height should determine the color a certain x/y region is colored in.

Here is the code I have been trying:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
z = []
for index in range(100):
    a = random.random()
    b = random.random()
    c = np.exp(-a*a - b*b)
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)
    z.append(c)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=cmap)
```

But it gives an error

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Maybe I am trying the wrong thing?

**Remark**: The three lists x,y,z and calculated for the example above, but in reality I have just three lists with "random" numbers in it I want to vizualize. I cannot calculate z given x and y.

I could also use `imshow` to create the plot I want, but I have to convert my original data into a matrix first. Maybe there is a function I can use?

Answer (score 2):

`pcolormesh` might not be the choice for this kind of problem. `pcolormesh` expects ordered cell edges as data rather than random data points. You could do this if you know your grid before hand e.g.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 51)
# meshgrid makes a 2D grid of points
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, x)

z = np.exp(-xx**2 - yy*2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, z, cmap="PiYG")
```

which will give you

[image]

Alternatively, you could use one of the `tri` functions such as [`tripcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tripcolor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tripcolor) with your existing setup

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
z = []
for index in range(100):
    a = random.random()
    b = random.random()
    c = np.exp(-a*a - b*b)
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)
    z.append(c)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tripcolor(x, y, z, cmap="PiYG")
```

which will give
[image]

Note it would be simpler to use `np.random` to generate your data

```py
x, y = np.random.random(size=(2, 100))
z = np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tripcolor(x, y, z, cmap="PiYG")
```

Comment: x,y,z are random data. I just choose to create them with `random` to have a minimal reproducible example. But in the end, they are just independent, single data points

Comment: Ok, so you can use `tripcolor` as I suggest. Or is that not possible for you?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. I just wanted to make sure. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with `x`, `y` and `z` shapes: they have to be 2D arrays (matrices) but they are 1-dimensional.
In order to generate `x` and `y` axis, you could use:

```
x = []
y = []
for index in range(100):
    x.append(random.random())
    y.append(random.random())
```

Then you have to create a [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

Finally you can compute `Z` over the meshgrid:

```
Z = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
```

In this way, your code:

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=cmap)
```

gives:

[image]

---

If you you cannot compute `Z` on the meshgrid, then you should not use `pcolormesh`.
Some alternative could be:

- 3D scatterplot:

  ```
  import random
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  x = []
  y = []
  z = []
  for index in range(100):
      a = random.random()
      b = random.random()
      c = np.exp(-a*a - b*b)
      x.append(a)
      y.append(b)
      z.append(c)

  cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')

  ax.scatter(x, y, z, cmap=cmap)

  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]
- 2D colored scatterplot:

  ```
  import random
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  x = []
  y = []
  z = []
  for index in range(100):
      a = random.random()
      b = random.random()
      c = np.exp(-a*a - b*b)
      x.append(a)
      y.append(b)
      z.append(c)

  cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')

  plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()

  ax.scatter(x, y, c = z, cmap=cmap)

  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]

Comment: No, that solution does not work. In my example, I did calculate the value for 'z' by a function. In reality, I just have values for z I want to plot, I have no way of calculating them. I only have three lists with "random" numbers (they are not random, but cannot be calculated)